# how to query portal roles added to the public group in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, roles, public-group

I have a public group and many Portal Roles added to that along with other users. How do I query all the portal roles added to this public group in SOQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you know the Group Id(lets say your group name is `MyCoolUsers`). If not, you can query on `Group` object against the `developername` of the Group.

Next, you need to query on `GroupMember` object and find out which all groups are part of this Group. Yes, the roles are stored as Groups in `GroupMember`. Bear with me, I will explain.

```
SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember where GroupId = :groupId
```

This will return both `UserIds` and `GroupIds`. So you need to pass it through a for loop and catch only the ones starting with `00G`(keyPrefix of Group object)

Example of query result:

[image]

The ones starting with `00G` are the ones you need.

```
for(GroupMember gm : [SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember where GroupId = :groupId])
{
  if(gm.UserOrGroupId.startsWith('00G'))
    roleGroupIdList.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
}
```

Now you have a list of groupIds which belongs to your actual group, `MyCoolUsers`.

Next, fire a SOQL on Group object against the Id matching with `roleGroupIdList`.

```
SELECT Id,RelatedId FROM Group where Id IN :roleGroupIdList
```

You see the `RelatedId`? That field holds the actual Portal Role Ids you want.